# Proving that matrix is invertible

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse

Let $I$ be an identity matrix of size $3$ and let $A$ be the matrix of size $3$ having three different nonzero eigenvalues.

Prove that matrix $A + A^{-1} + I$ is invertible.

I was trying to somehow show that determinant is different than zero, but I am not sure if this is good approach.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What is the base field?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing more is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix could be singular. For example let $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\-1&-1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$

Then $A+A^{-1}+I=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&3\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: The result is incorrect. The example shows that the matrix could be not invertible.

Comment: As soon as any eigenvalue of A satisfies equation $x^2+x+1=0$, matrix $A+A^{-1}+I$ is singular; otherwise, the matrix is non-singular

Comment: So i can't prove it, @ZhaohuiDu gave counter example, right? This is whole task, but maybe they mentioned on exam that eigenvalues must be real, does this change anything?

Comment: @Berto, good proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have three different eigenvalues, you can diagonalize $A = T D T^{-1} $, where $ D$ is the diagonal matrix with the three different eigenvalues on the diagonal. Now,

$$ A + A^{-1} + I = T (D + D^{-1} + I)T^{-1}.$$

Use this to say something about the eigenvalues of the matrix.

In response to your comment: The above formula gives you 
$$ \tilde\lambda_i = \lambda_i +\lambda_i^{-1} + 1 $$ for the new eigenvalues, where $ \lambda_i $ are the eigenvalues of $A$. Therfore

$$ \tilde\lambda_i = 0 \iff  \lambda_i^2 + \lambda_i + 1 = 0  .$$

Since above polynomial does not have any real roots, the statement holds, if the eigenvalues of $A$ are required to be real. If the eigenvalues are allowed to be complex, the statement fails, since the polynomial then has zeros. An example is given in the other answer.

Comment: This looks like it, but can you explain why it doesn't work for comples eigenvalues?

Comment: @Berto Because if $x$ is an eigenvalue (which is to say, a diagonal entry) of $D$, then $x + \frac1x + 1$ is the corresponding eigenvalue of $D+D^{-1} + I$. And no real number $x$ makes that $0$, but there are complex numbers that do.